# htaccess redirect retains part of old url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Updating a site and have a ton of redirects. 
The issue is that the new URL retains part of the old for all, as seen in the following example:

```
Redirect 301 /old/oldfile.html /new
```

redirects to:

```
http://url.com/new/oldfile.html
```

Aside from the redirects the htaccess contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    Options +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

 # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite instead. This should go above the other rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^old/oldfile.html /new [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This results in the same retention of the old url data

Comment: This worked. I just needed to remove any other mod_alias directives and stick with rewrite. Thanks.